# How to populate data in a tableView as alphabetical order while using section index

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm implementing an app where i need to show a tableView. tableView needs to have alphabetical  search on the right side by clicking on any letter it needs to show data starting with that letter. I've implemented the vertical alphabet search and when user clicks on any letter it takes user to that particular section. But the problem is every section has the same data it's  not populating according to alphabet.

Here is my code for this. 
// Here `exhibitorArray` contains all the info to populate data in tableView.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.exhibitorArray count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return [[[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionTitles] objectAtIndex:section];
    }

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionIndexTitles];

    }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
        return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex:index];


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.exhibitorArray count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    [self.exhibitorTableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

    UIView* bgview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
    bgview.opaque = YES;
    bgview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:244.0f/255 green:245.0f/255 blue:246.0f/255 alpha:1.0];
    [cell setBackgroundView:bgview];

    UIImageView *defaultImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    [defaultImage setFrame:CGRectMake(5.0f, 5.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f)];
    [cell addSubview:defaultImage];

    NSString *urlString = @"http://";
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.exhibitorArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"image"]]];
    NSLog(@"%@",urlString);

    AsyncImageView *asyncImageView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f)];
    [asyncImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [asyncImageView loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [defaultImage addSubview:asyncImageView];
    defaultImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    asyncImageView = nil;
    defaultImage = nil;

    NSString *name_string = [[self.exhibitorArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"name"];

    UILabel *user_name = [[ UILabel alloc]init ];
    [user_name setFrame:(CGRectMake(58, 5, 270, 25))];
    [user_name setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
    [user_name setText:name_string];
    [user_name setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:14]];
    [user_name setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    [user_name setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:93.0f/255 green:94.0f/255 blue:94.0f/255 alpha:1.0]];
    [cell addSubview:user_name];
    user_name = nil;

    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    return cell;
}
```

output of this is coming something like this.
[image]

Comment: Please show cellForRowAtIndextPath

Comment: sure.. edited my question, you can check now.

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/chsectionselectionview

Comment: Look http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/indexed-uitableview-tutorial/

Comment: i tried to understand this but couldn't clearly understand

Answer (score 1):

The following is wrong:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.exhibitorArray count];
}
```

You have to separate your arrays for every section. Let's say a different array for letter 'A' and a different array for letter 'B' and so on. Then, based on the section index, you will get the data for the correct array.

For example you can use an array of arrays like this `array[section][index]` or a dictionary like this `dict['A'][index]`.

So the above function has to be:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // based on array of arrays
    return [[self.exhibitorArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] count];
}
```

and then, in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you can use

```
NSString *name_string = [[[self.exhibitorArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
```

---

**Update: Convert exhibitorArray**

```
- (void)convertArray
{
    //NSMutableArray *exhibitorArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[@"abra", @"Catabra"]];

    NSArray *data = [exhibitorArray copy];
    exhibitorArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:27];
    // 27 elements, 26 for A-Z plus one for '#'
    for (int i=0; i<27; i++)  
        [exhibitorArray addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];

    int firstAsciiPos = (int)[@"A" characterAtIndex:0];
    for (int i=0; i<[data count]; i++)
    {
        int index = (int)[[[data objectAtIndex:i] uppercaseString] characterAtIndex:0] - firstAsciiPos;
        if (index < 0 || index > 25)
        {
            // it is not between A and Z, add it to '#'
            index = 26;
        }
        [[exhibitorArray objectAtIndex:index] addObject:[data objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

The above code converts your array to a two-dimensional array based on alphabet letters. Please feel free to change it according to your code and don't forget to handle memory deallocations if you are not using ARC.

Comment: when m using this `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // based on array of arrays
    return [[self.exhibitorArray objectAtIndex:section] objectAtIndex:row];
}` 
it is giving me an error like."use of undeclare identifier row." you want me to declare row as separate thing.

Comment: My mistake, as of my edited answer, you have to ask for the count of the array. As it is obvious but worth mentioning, you have to structure your data before starting to populate the tableview cells.

Comment: When you say i have to separate my data structure before populating. what you mean by this. I have to have a kind of different array for every letter or something because i think i'm going wrong in making proper array for my data.

Comment: Exactly. I suggest you create an array with 26 elements (as the length of the alphabet). Each element is an array. For example, the first element of your exhibitorArray will contain an array with all the elements starting from 'A'. Then, the second element of exhibitorArray will be an array with let's say zero elements. That means that you have no records starting from 'B'. And so on. Push your data accordingly to the different arrays based on their initial.

Comment: i tried but no luck yet, can you help me with some code for this.

Comment: I kindly ask you to post an update if it worked or not, since it might be useful for the people that read this thread in the future. Also, don't forget to mark it as answered if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering but i chose to do it in a different way.

Comment: No problem, you might want to share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method "`sortedArrayUsingSelector`":

When you got your array filled to show your data, just after:

```
exhibitorArray=[exhibitorArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

**EDIT**:
Your array contains `Dictionarys`? I use this on my code. Use the correct Key you want use to sort your objects. In my case is "name":

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];    

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor, nil]; 

exhibitorArray= [exhibitorArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: it didn't help actually i have tried this before. 
    'NSSortDescriptor *nameSorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    [self.exhibitorArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nameSorter]];

    self.dataList2 = self.exhibitorArray;`